# Solving system of linear equations across network in Python

Tags: systems-of-equations, python, network

I have a network and I would like to calculate the voltage drop across  the nodes (2-5). I know `V1=10` and `V6=0`. The equations at each node are written as follows. There are 4 equations and 4 unknowns.

2: `V1/R12 - V2*(1/R12 + 1/R24) + V4/R24 = 0`
3: `V1/R13 - V3*(1/R13 + 1/R34 + 1/R35) + V4/R34 + V5/R35 = 0`
4: `V2/R24 + V3/R34 - V4*(1/R24 + 1/R34 + 1/R46) + V6/R46 = 0`
5: `V3/R35 - V5*(1/R35 + 1/R56) + V6/R56 = 0`

Is there a way to implement it in Python? Manually generating the matrices is tedious for a very large network, say with 100 nodes.

[Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYejo.png)

Comment: Try to ask in https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: You can implement reduction of a matrix to RREF (reduced row echelon form) using Python.  Then you can feed any augmented matrix to this routine to solve for the unknowns for any dimension $n$.  This procedure of RREF reduction is straight forward and can be implemented in any programming language without much effort.

Comment: I have included an answer for solving for the voltages given the equations.  Is this what you're looking for, or do you want to write code to generate the equations from the network layout ?

Comment: If what you're looking for is how to generate the equations from the network layout, then you have to search on the internet for the mesh method of solving a network, and may be you should direct your question to the electrical engineering exchange website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code in Visual Basic to reduce an $m \times n$ matrix $(a)$ to RREF (reduce row echelon form).

```
Public Sub reduce_matrix(a, ByVal m As Integer, ByVal n As Integer, ByRef det As Double)

Dim i, j, k, k1, krow As Integer
Dim amax As Double, kmax As Integer

eps = 1.E-8


krow = 1
det = 1

For i = 1 To n
    
    k1 = 0

    amax = Abs(a(krow, i))
    kmax = 0
    For k = krow To m

    If Abs(a(k, i)) > eps Then
       If Abs(a(k, i)) >= amax Then
          kmax = k
          amax = Abs(a(k, i))
       End If
      
    End If

Next k

If kmax <> 0 Then
   k1 = kmax
End If


If k1 = 0 Then
   det = 0
   GoTo lnext_i
End If

If k1 <> krow Then

' interchange rows k1 and krow

   For j = 1 To n

      t = a(k1, j)
      a(k1, j) = a(krow, j)
      a(krow, j) = t

   Next j
   det = -det
       
End If


'  normalize krow-th row

   t = a(krow, i)

   If Abs(t - 1) > eps Then
   
   For j = i To n
   
   a(krow, j) = a(krow, j) / t
   
   Next j
   
   det = det * t
    
   End If
   
' eleminate elements in column i
    
For i1 = 1 To m

If i1 <> krow Then

   factor = -a(i1, i)
   If factor = 0 Then GoTo lnext_i1
          
   For j = i To n
   
   a(i1, j) = a(i1, j) + factor * a(krow, j)
   
   Next j
   
End If

lnext_i1:
Next i1
    
krow = krow + 1

If krow > m Then Exit For

lnext_i:

Next i



End Sub
```